# JavaScript: Why does closure only happen if I assign the return function to a variable?

Tags: javascript, closures

Even after reading [You don't know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS) and [JavaScript: The Core](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/javascript-the-core-2nd-edition/) I still couldn't understand the behavior of the following code.

Why, when I call `counter()()`, do I get no closure, but if I assign a variable to the result of `counter()`, like `var getClosure = counter()`, I then get a closure when calling `getClosure()`?

```
function counter() {

    var _counter = 0;

    function increase() { return _counter++ }

    return increase;
}

// Double ()() to call the returned function always return 0, so no closure. 
counter()() // returns 0
counter()() // returns 0
counter()() // returns 0
counter()() // returns 0

var createClosure = counter();

createClosure() // returns 0
createClosure() // returns 1
createClosure() // returns 2
createClosure() // returns 3
```

Comment: `counter()` creates a NEW closure each time?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`_counter` is the local variable within function `counter()`. Every time when you call `counter()` a new `_counter` will be created.

But `var createClosure = counter()` only called the function 1 time, that's why `_counter` is not newly created every time and 'remembered' there (that's where closure happens)

Comment: Thanks Xin, looks so obvious in hindsight.

Comment: @sandre89 closures fall into a category of concepts with that property: they are very hard to wrap your brain around but seem totally obvious and even trivial in retrospect. Wait until you get to monads...

Answer (score 13):

**Each time** you call `counter()()`, it creates a new function and a new closure.
So the result is always `0`.

On the contrary, when `var createClosure = counter();` is executed, a function and closure are created and **saved** in the variable `createClosure`. Next time when you call `createClosure()`, the saved one is invoked and the created closure is used. Therefore the results are `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, ...

Answer (score 1):

To put in another way, the return value of the `counter()` function, which is the closure, isn't persisted or rather it is discarded when you simply call the function as is.

However after assigning that return value to 
`var createClosure`. You are able to call the closure as many times as needed