# I was going through the topic "Closures" in JS, and tried to do some experiment with this concept. I created two Function and checking there output

Tags: javascript, function, scope

both function print the value inside the "outer" and "inner" function twice.

using simple function declaration & execution

```js
function outer1() {
  var j = 20;

  function inner1() {
    var k = 30;
    console.log(j, k);
    j++;
    k++;
  }
  inner1(); //calling inner1 
  return;
}

outer1(); // calling function 2 times
outer1();
```

```
output : // same output both time
20 30
20 30
```

-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x//

using function expression

```js
function outer() {
  var a = 20;
  var inner = function() {
    var b = 30;
    console.log(a, b);
    a++;
    b++;
  }
  return inner; //returning inner
}

var func = outer();

func(); // calling function 2 times
func();
```

```
output : // value of a is incremented by 1 time.
20 30
21 30
```

I am confused, why both are showing different result ?, why output remain same for the
first one but different for second one ?

Comment: Because the first one you reset `var j = 20;` every time you call the function! The second one you are returning the inner function so it does not call `var a = 20;` every time you call. Adding basic console.log statements can show you how the code is working.

Comment: Similar reasoning to this question: [JavaScript: Why does closure only happen if I assign the return function to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47342760) (hopefully you can see how it relates)

Answer (score 1):

With the first example, you run `outer()` multiple times. This creates a new inner function each time, each with the initial value of `j`.

If you're familiar with classes, this is kind of like calling `new Thing().do(); new Thing().do();` vs `const thing = new Thing(); thing.do(); thing.do();`